# jQuery: how to get table cell data and append it to input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I am trying to get each value of table column and append to input field. So far I have this code below and it returns `[object Object]` on each click of each object from `.token` class. How do I reference the particular object that is being clicked to append to the input field?

```js
$(function () {
    $('.token').on('click', function () {
        var url = $('#url');
        var tkn = $('.token');
        url.val(url.val() + tkn);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-sm-10">
  <input type="url" class="form-control" name="e_postback_url" size="60" placeholder="URL" value="URL" id="url" maxlength="1024">
 </div>
</div>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover tc-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="token">Token</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="token" id="token1">[commission_id]</td>
            <td class="typedesc">Numeric-16</td>
            <td class="typedesc">Unique order ID of the commission</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="token" id="token2">[offer_id]</td>
            <td class="typedesc">Numeric-10</td>
            <td class="typedesc">Unique offer ID</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="token" id="token3">[payout]</td>
        <td class="typedesc">Decimal-20,2</td>
        <td class="typedesc">Amount of the commission in EUR</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, get the targetted element value and append it.

```js
$(function () {
    $('.token').on('click', function (event) {
        var url = $('#url');
        var tkn = event.target
        url.val(url.val() + tkn.textContent);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-sm-10">
  <input type="url" class="form-control" name="e_postback_url" size="60" placeholder="URL" value="URL" id="url" maxlength="1024">
 </div>
</div>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover tc-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="token">Token</th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="token" id="token1">[commission_id]</td>
                            <td class="typedesc">Numeric-16</td>
                            <td class="typedesc">Unique order ID of the commission</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="token" id="token2">[offer_id]</td>
                            <td class="typedesc">Numeric-10</td>
                            <td class="typedesc">Unique offer ID</td>
                        </tr>
                     <tr>
                      <td class="token" id="token3">[payout]</td>
                      <td class="typedesc">Decimal-20,2</td>
                      <td class="typedesc">Amount of the commission in EUR</td>
                     </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: :) with pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

For take the text inside element which get clicked, use:

```
var token = $(this).text()
```

Where $(this) represent the element clicked and text the text inside the tag.

Answer (score 0):

check snippet below..

```js
/*$(function () {
    $('.token').on('click', function () {
        var url = $('#url');
        var tkn = $('.token');
        url.val(url.val() + tkn);
    });
});*/

var urlVal = $('#url').val();
$('.token').click(function(){
  urlVal = urlVal + $(this).text();
  $('#url').val(urlVal); 
  console.log(urlVal);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-sm-10">
  <input type="url" class="form-control" name="e_postback_url" size="60" placeholder="URL" value="URL" id="url" maxlength="1024">
 </div>
</div>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover tc-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="token">Token</th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="token" id="token1">[commission_id]</td>
                            <td class="typedesc">Numeric-16</td>
                            <td class="typedesc">Unique order ID of the commission</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="token" id="token2">[offer_id]</td>
                            <td class="typedesc">Numeric-10</td>
                            <td class="typedesc">Unique offer ID</td>
                        </tr>
                     <tr>
                      <td class="token" id="token3">[payout]</td>
                      <td class="typedesc">Decimal-20,2</td>
                      <td class="typedesc">Amount of the commission in EUR</td>
                     </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```